# Не удается установить kde5 на Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

Tags: linux, terminal, kde

Система Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa. Kernel 4.4.0-040400-generic
На данный момент установлен kde

```
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE: 4.14.13
```

при добавлении репозитория с kde5

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/ppa
```

у меня появляется ошибка в виде hex cod`a

```
'\xd0\x94\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 PPA \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 trusty'
Не удаётся добавить PPA: «'\xd0\x94\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 PPA \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 trusty'».
```

Перевожу на нормальный  чтения язык
для
    'Данный PPA не поддерживает trusty'Не удаётся добавить PPA: «'Данный PPA не поддерживает trusty'».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как слепо что-то добавлять с левой статьи в интернетах, посмотрите, что за репозиторий: https://launchpad.net/~neon:

> This team is no longer in use.
>
> If you are interested in the concept have a look at
>   http://neon.kde.org.uk

собственно нужен второй пункт отсюда: http://neon.kde.org/download#packageUpgrade

одно но: они пишут, мол саппортят ресентли lts, но в рекомендациях говорят ставить Ubuntu 15.10. Мята 17 в своей основе 14.04 содержит. Так что, я бы в песочнице сначала побаловался.

**UPD:** по информации [отсюда](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=43790):

> Пакеты планируют формировать для LTS-выпусков Ubuntu, но до момента
>   релиза Ubuntu 16.04, будут публиковаться сборки для Ubuntu 15.10.
>   Пакеты выпускаются только для архитектуры amd64.

Т.е.:

1. Ubuntu 14.04/trusty, Mint 17.x - в пролёте.
2. x86_32 - в пролёте.

По поводу решения:

1. Набраться терпения: 16.04 выпустят в этом месяце, мяту 18 через 1-2 месяца после. Может раньше.
2. Обновить железо, если не x86_64. Без вариантов. Либо пересобрать самому :)

Comment: Ошибка: Не удалось найти пакет neon-desktop. Печально

Comment: Ну, что и требовалось доказать: ждите выхода убунты 16.04 и мяты 18. Ну и вот инфа, которая подтверждает это: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=43790: "Пакеты планируют формировать для LTS-выпусков Ubuntu, но до момента релиза Ubuntu 16.04, будут публиковаться сборки для Ubuntu 15.10. Пакеты выпускаются только для архитектуры amd64.", так что с 14.04/trusty и Mint 17.x - в пролёте. Ну ничего, пару месяцев подождать осталось (в этом должны выпустить убунту, потом ждать адаптации мяты)